# Can iOS dictation be made to stick to a single language?

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

I'm using the dictation feature in iOS a fair bit, and as a multilingual speaker I do so in several languages. However, one very annoying feature (and I believe it to be recent) is that it will occasionally switch languages mid-sentence.

This behavior can be both good and bad: when my input language is set to Dutch and I'm obviously speaking English, my phone happily corrects the input language and uses English instead.

On the other hand, my Spanish comes with a strong Dutch accent and so my phone decides that I must be speaking Dutch and creates something incomprehensible.

Can this feature be turned off so that I may use dictation in multiple languages properly? :-)